# -Windows 10 Home Signin takes a really long time (like around 10 minutes)

Tags: windows-10, login, login-screen, windows-defender, anti-malware

Here are the details about my computer:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Installed RAM 16.0GB
- 64-Bit Operation System, x64-based processor
- Windows 10 Home
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0

My Windows Sign-in (which is just a regular Sign-In with No password) takes a really really long time ( like around 10 minutes) to sign-in.

I restarted windows in Safe Mode, and it still took a really long time.

Therefore, Safe Mode allowed me to sort of eliminate Non-essential applications, and helped determine that it was some standard/basic windows application(s)/process(es)/task(s) that is causing the sign-in to take so long:

[image]

In the above snapshot of the Task Manager which in Safe Mode, I organized it by memory usage in descending order.  It seems that Microsoft Defender Antivirus Service's Antimalware service executable takes a lot of memory.  However, I am concerned about disabling anything associated with Microsoft Defender Antivirus Service in order to make my Sign-in run faster because Microsoft Defender Antivirus Service protects my computer from malware.

Could someone please suggest some kind of reconfiguration and/or modification of my Windows 10 instance that would be still ensure that my computer is protected from malware but at the same time makes my Windows Sign-in run faster?

**Update** (But still Signin is Too Long):
[image]

Comment: 1. Windows Defender does not slow down startup of a properly setup computer. Do you have a competing Anti Virus installed and active?  2. Doe you have a Hard Drive or SSD. One HDD machine here shows the desktop in about 3 minutes and is smoothly running in about 5 or 6 minutes. SSDs are significantly faster.  3,  Of your list above, does Text input application take a long time to start. ? These are some initial thoughts.

Comment: I just restarted my HDD laptop. It took almost 10 minutes for the hard drive to stop trashing and work smoothly. Is this what your machine is doing?

Comment: No, I don't think that I have any Hard drive problems.  It's just the Windows 10 Sign-in that takes a really long time.  Just FYI, I did partition my computer to have have Ubuntu and Windows on the same hard drive. When I restart the computer, I get a "bootup" screen that asks me if I want Ubuntu or Windows, and I'm wondering if it's the partitioning that is causing the problem.

Comment: The machine above only has one operating system (Windows 10 21H next) and this machine I am on uses Virtual Machines to avoid dual boot. What happens (and what time does it take) to select the Windows Boot sequence as soon as it appears?

Comment: The dual boot screen shows up really quickly when I startup/restartup the computer.  Also, just FYI, if I select Ubuntu then Ubuntu starts up really quickly.  However, it's just when I select Windows, and then click on the Windows "Signin" button that everything takes a really long time.

Comment: Does the Windows machine have Hibernation enabled?  I would disable this. Is Fast Start ON or OFF.  I keep Fast Start ON but I do not know if this affects dual boot.

Comment: Please see my update.  Still Sign-in takes too long.

Comment: I looked at that. Are you using legacy BIOS to allow dual boot?  Otherwise I have run out of ideas.